# Sorting Four Dimensional array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I want to sort four dimensional array based on 1 column by using following method,

```
var main_arr = [
    []
];
var hdnFromValues = [11,16,12,17,14,18,15];
var hdnToValues = [12,17,13,18,15,19,16];
var hdnSPIDs = [11,12,13,14,0,0,0];
var hdnFlag = [D,E,E,D,A,A,A];
for (var j = 0; j < hdnFromValues.length; j++) {
    var temp_arr = [];
    var HdnToValue;
    temp_arr.push(hdnFromValues[j]);
    temp_arr.push(hdnToValues[j]);
    temp_arr.push(hdnSPIDs[j]);
    temp_arr.push(hdnFlag[j]);
    main_arr.push(temp_arr);
    temp_arr = null;
}
main_arr.sort(sort_by_col);
hdnFrom = "";
hdnTo = "";
spid = "";
flags = "";
for (var i = 1; i < main_arr.length; i++) {
    hdnFrom = hdnFrom.concat(main_arr[i][0], ",");
    hdnTo = hdnTo.concat(main_arr[i][1], ",");
    spid = spid.concat(main_arr[i][2], ",");
    flags = flags.concat(main_arr[i][3], ",");
}
hdnFrom = hdnFrom.substring(0, hdnFrom.length - 1);
hdnTo = hdnTo.substring(0, hdnTo.length - 1);
spid = spid.substring(0, spid.length - 1);
flags = flags.substring(0, flags.length - 1);
alert(hdnFrom);
alert(hdnTo);
alert(spid);
alert(flags);

function sort_by_col(a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
}
```

Sometimes, 3 & 4th column not arranging correctly as per 1st column.

Will someone help me?

[**JSFilddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/GTE7W/1/)

Comment: give your full code, & failing case, what is sometime?

Comment: you sort on the first col, why would the 3rd or 4th be sorted any more than happenstance?

Comment: @dandavis sorting first column, based on that entire row should change.

Comment: @VijayakumarS: yeah the row moves, but you need to look at what you sort to sort it. if you never check the later columns, how would they ever be sorted by anything other than coincidence?

Comment: @Mritunjay Code added

Comment: what ever you are getting is expected.

Comment: @Mritunjay will u check this fiddle & confirm? http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/GTE7W/1/

Comment: because you are saying that sort it with `0th` index so it just guarantees that the first column will be ordered not others.

Comment: @Mritunjay OK, what is the best way for four dimensional sorting? Want to sort based on 0th Index, all other indexes should moves along with 0th index. OR My sorting method is correct?

Comment: That's a twodimensional array at least, if not a onedimensional [array of (number-indexed) objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
function sort_by_col(a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
}
```

to

```
function sort_by_col(a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1];
}
```